# php - curl POST User Input and Hard-coded Query

Tags: php, curl

How can I post some known queries (hard-coded) together with user input? 
For example, if I did not need user input, the query would look like this:

`$post = "userid=11&token=abcdef&action=set&name=cf_1&value=UserInput";`

But, since I need the value from users, I make something like this:

```
    <form action="submit.php" method="post>
        Insert cf_1: <input name='value' type='text'>
        <input value="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
```

And the php script:

```
<?php
    $url = someurl;
    $post = "userid=11&token=abcdef&action=set&name=cf_1";
    $options = array( CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                      CURLOPT_POST => true,
                      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post
                    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

However, using the above form and php script, the user input couldn't be submitted to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post .= '&value='.$_POST['value'];`

Make sure you do the necessary cleaning of the $_POST value, though.